# A pond contains red and golden fish. A probability problem.

Tags: probability, independence

A pond contains red and golden fish. There are $3000$ red and $7000$ golden fish, of which $200$ and $500$
respectively, are tagged. Find the probability that a random sample of $100 $ red and $200$ golden fish will show
$15$ and $20$ tagged fish, respectively

My input :

$A$: Choosing $15$ tagged redfish

$B$: Choosing $20$ tagged golden fish

$P$($A$ and $B$)=$P(A)P(B)$   $\ \ \ \ \ \because $ Given its random sample.

$\dfrac{\binom{100}{15}\binom{2800}{85}}{{3000}\choose{100}}\cdot\dfrac{\binom{500}{20}\binom{6500}{180}}{{7000}\choose{200}}$

I think I have done something wrong. I don't have the answer to this question in my textbook so please someone check it.

Comment: Where does $2975$ come from?  Where does $75$ come from?   And $6980$?  And $80$?

Comment: Definitely a typo.

Comment: @lulu Wait I ve messed up somthing . Let me edit it.

Comment: @lulu now see it .

Comment: $15+75\neq 100$ and  $20+80\neq 200$.

Comment: @lulu omg I want to die.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{\binom{3000 - 200 }{100 - 15}\binom{200 }{15}}{\binom{3000}{100}} 
\times\frac{\binom{7000 - 500 }{200 - 20}\binom{500 }{20}}{\binom{7000}{200}}
$$